# How to write regexp that will trim HTML text with nested tags?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Trying to find a single regex that will transform:

```
"    <p>   Some text <span> with another text   </span>    </p>  "
```

into:

```
"<p>Some text <span> with another text</span></p>"
```

The problem is I can't find solution to group tags that left from right and left side.

What I created so far is:

```
/((?:^(?:\s|(?:<[\/]*[\w]+>))+)|(?:\s|(?:<[\/]*[\w]+>))+$)/
```

This might work as a workaround but it will be two-step solution (so first: find both left and right side and second remove spaces outside of tags).

Looking for something more elegant, that will resolve my problem with one single substitution using regex. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yuck.  Don't do that.  Use an HTML/XML parser instead.  Even if you crank out a pattern that seems to work, it could easily break on HTML content you have not seen/tested before.

Comment: How should the regex decide which tags to leave surrounded by spaces (like `<span>` in your example) and which ones not (like `<p>`)?

Comment: Maybe I did not made my point correctly: I want to trim string from both ends leaving all tags in place but remove just spaces between them untill real text. I was also thinking to remove just text nodes (in terms of parsing HTML) but this is even more complex solution because of nested tags that have additional spaces like `" my text <p>   </p>    "`.

Comment: This comment hasn't really clarified your requirements. Please define clearly in exactly which circumstances you want spaces removed, and in which circumstances you want them trimmed to single spaces (and possibly in which circumstances you don't want to change them at all, e. g. in `<pre>` blocks?). Most probably, once you have defined the problem unambiguously, it will become apparent that one single regex is not going to cut it.

Comment: In this particular case I don't care about tag type. Spaces that are not in the tag have to be removed are before the first letter of actual text and after the last one. How is it ambiguous?

Answer (score 0):

this solution ain't regex, but it works:

```js
function trimElement(root, recursive=false){
  let todo = [root];
  while(todo.length){
    let elm = todo.pop();
    if(recursive) 
      todo.push(...elm.children);

    if(elm.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "script") continue;

    const {firstChild, lastChild} = elm;
    if(firstChild.nodeType === 3)
      firstChild.data = firstChild.data.trimLeft();

    if(lastChild.nodeType === 3)
      lastChild.data = lastChild.data.trimRight();
  }
  
  console.log(root.outerHTML);
}


trimElement(document.querySelector("div"), true);
```

```html
<div>
    <p>   Some text <span> with another text   </span>    </p>  
</div>
```

Comment: That was first thing that came to my mind before regular expression. It doesn't work for specific cases: like `"<div>This is<sup> text</sup</div>"`results with `"<div>This is<sup>text</sup</div>"`. It's loosing significant spacing.

Comment: OK, so how do **you** define *"significant"* whitespace in some general way. The problem is the same with regular expressions. You have to tell the engine what whitespace to remove, and what to keep.